# Rails 4: How do I do an AJAX call on nested forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to set up my form so that when the user changes the "position" drop down box selection it will update a partials with records that are related to that position.  I will do my best to include all relevant code below with the error shown first. If I've forgotten to include anything please let me know, thanks.

**Error (from the... jqXHR.responseText)**

```
AJAX Error: NameError in Players::Reports#update_position_specifics

Showing ../app/views/players/reports/update_position_specifics.js.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007f9b82ebdcf8>:0x007f9b82fc8030>
```

**reports.coffee**

```
  $(document).on 'change', '#report_position_id', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_position_specifics',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        position_graded_id: $("#report_position_id option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{jqXHR.responseText}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic position select OK!")
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@player, @report], html: {id: 'report-form'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :position, selected: @position_graded.id %>
  <div id="position_specifics"> 
    <%= render 'form_position_specifics', f: f %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_form_position_specifics.html.erb**

```
<%= f.nested_fields_for :evaluations,
      f.object.evaluations.target.sort_by! { |a| a.skill.order_by },
      wrapper_tag: :tr, wrapper_options: { class: 'fields' } do |fn| %>
     <% # Form fields here... %>
<% end %>
```

**update_position_specifics.js.erb**

```
$("#position_specifics").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form_position_specifcs', f: f") %>")
```

**reports_controller.rb**

```
def update_position_specifics
  # remove previous/existing position specific skill from evaluations
  @report.evaluations.joins(:skill).where(skills: { type: 'position specifcs'}).delete_all

  # add new position specifics from specified position
  @skills = Skill.joins(:positions).where(position_id: @position_graded.id)

  # Add new evaluations to report
  @skills.joins(:positions).where(positions: {id: @position_graded_id}, disabled: false).each do |skill|
    @report.evaluations << Evaluation.new(skill_id: skill.id
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

views/posts/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post, id: 'myform') do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :pictures do |ff| %>
    <% target = "picture-#{ff.object.id}-div-that-will-updated" %>

    <%= ff.select :category, 'data-target': target %>
    <%= ff.file_field :file %>

    <!-- This is the element that will be updated when <select> above is changed -->
    <div id='<%= target %>'></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

javascripts/posts/new.js

```
$('#myform').find('select').change(function() {
  // get the data-target of the <select>, then load that target element with the new partially loaded (current url) target element
  $( '#' + $(this).attr('data-target') )
    .load( window.location.href + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target') );
    // Take note of the space in ' #' above
}
```

In summary, what this all will do is when a user selects from a dropdown, the page is just reloaded. But instead of reloading the whole page, only the data-target element is updated. This also works for multiple nested associated records on the page.

Comment: This method would work but would require me to add a new case statement every time I wanted to add a new "position" to my database.  So I'm not sure this is the way I want to go... if I'm understanding your answer correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer to handle multiple nested records, to prevent conflicts. I also removed my implementation for the `views/posts/new.js.erb`, and simplified the process. The drawback however because of this simplification is that you won't be able to customize a custom JS response, but rather that it will always just gonna be a partially loaded HTML response (which I think is what you said you want).

Comment: Am I missing something or does this new way reload the entire page, which would remove it's asynchronous functionality?

Comment: This will reload the current page's target element asynchronously. Every time you change a dropdown selector in the form, that <select>'s "data-target" attribute (i.e. 'picture-24-div-that-will-updated') will be updated. The  same controller/action will be still called, and you will get a response body of the full HTML page of the same page, except only that only a part of the page will be updated. This is an easier fast approach, but the downside is that all AJAX requests take more bandwidth (because the server still actually sends the whole HTML)